# Convergence of a simple Integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be continuous on the interval $[0, 1]$. How can I show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x)\sin nx\,dx = 0 ?$$

Comment: In the case when $f\in C^1[0,1]$ it can be shown using integration by parts, then approximating continuous function by continuously differentable functions.

Comment: I know integration by parts but I'm not sure what you mean, can you show me the rest of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in C^1[0,1]$ then
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\sin nx\, dx = -\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 f(x)\,d\cos nx =$$ 
$$= \frac{-1}{n}\left(f(1)\cos n - f(0)\cos 0 \right) + \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 f'(x)\cos nx\, dx \to 0 \quad\text{ as }\quad n\to\infty$$
since the right integral already exists and can be esimated by 
$$\int_0^1|f'(x)|\,dx.$$
After this approximate continuous function by continuously differentable functions.

Comment: AH ok, thank you very much!